# Generating an array from enum values

Tags: java, enums

Let's say I have an enum as such:

```
public enum Fruit {
    APPLES("Apples"),
    BANANAS("Bananas"),
    PEAR("Pear"),
    ORANGE("Oranges");

    private final String string;

    Fruit(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to generate a `String[]` array containing the string values of the enum, i.e. `"Apples", "Bananas, "Pear", "Oranges"`

I can think of a few ways but they could get messy and I'm wondering if there is a direct way to get these values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the shortest one I could come up with:

```
Arrays.stream(Fruit.values()).map(Fruit::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Fruit.getName() would be a method returning the `string` field in the Enum

Comment: Upvote because of using Java8 syntax. This is the only up-to-date solution.

Comment: I'd says that `Arrays.stream(Fruit.values())` would be better than `EnumSet.allOf(Fruit.class).stream()`, being shorter and not requiring the creation of an `EnumSet`.

Comment: Good point, my mind instantly went for an EnumSet (as that's what I most commonly use) without thinking over other options. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like this.

```
Arrays.toString(Fruit.values()).replaceAll("^.|.$", "").split(", ");
```

Comment: In my case there may be certain enum constants whose "name" string does not match the enum constant's name. So I wouldn't wanna do it as such.

Comment: @andrewDev15 What "name" string? Did you mean the field called `string`? Is that supposed to be the "name"? You didn't show whether that field is returned by a `getString()`, `getName()`, or `toString()` method. Assuming the last, which is not a bad assumption given the name of the field, this code does what you want. Perhaps you show give better code in the question, if you want to clarify differently.